# Perl scripting - pipe all outputs to the same terminal (how?)

Tags: perl, unix, console, stdout

I am calling a chain of Perl scripts and I want all stdout/stderr to arrive at the command line. 
I have two scripts:

**A.pl**

```
print "Hello from A\n";
`perl B.pl`;
print "Back to A\n";
```

**B.pl**

```
print "Hello from B\n";
```

When I call *perl A.pl*, I get:

```
Hello from A
Back to A
```

but what I would like to see is

```
Hello from A
Hello from B
Back to A
```

Of course I can change A and explicitly print the output from B, like so:

```
my $output = `perl B.pl`;
print $output;
```

but since my scripts are quite complicated I would like to avoid it. Is there a general way of stating that everything shoudl print out to the same terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use system instead of the backticks the output will go to the terminal.  Backticks are specifically for capturing the output of the other process:

```
print "Hello from A\n";
system('perl B.pl');
print "Back to A\n";
```

Comment: Simple and straight foward, I knew I was missing something basic! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, stop using backticks if you don't want to capture output!

What's wrong with simply doing `system $^X, "B.pl";`?